# How blocks handles __weak references

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks

From a huge number of questions about breaking retain cycles inside blocks, my question is the following:

How does the block actually handles `__weak` references inside of it?

I am aware of this (taken from [here](http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2009/10/how-blocks-are-implemented-and.html)):

> Blocks will retain any NSObject that they use from their enclosing
>   scope when they are copied.

So how does it takes care of the `__weak` qualification ownership? In theory since it is `__weak` it won't retain it? Will just keep a reference to it?

Comment: Read this section "Use Lifetime Qualifiers to Avoid Strong Reference Cycles" in the ARC Programming Guide.

Comment: The point is not to avoid the reference cycles @DavidH, it's how block deal while retaining objects that are qualified as `__weak`. In theory should not be retained, but just wanted to be sure about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct, the weak references will not be retained. It works precisely as you would expect. They are set to `nil` once the object is deallocated.

While this is generally good (you don't want it to be retained by the mere existence of the block), sometimes it can be problematic. Often you want to make sure that once the block beings executing, it's retained for the duration of the execution of that block (but not prior to the execution of the block). For that, you can use the `weakSelf`/`strongSelf` pattern:

```
__weak MyClass *weakSelf = self;

self.block = ^{
    MyClass *strongSelf = weakSelf;

    if (strongSelf) {
        // ok do you can now do a bunch of stuff, using strongSelf
        // confident that you won't lose it in the middle of the block,
        // but also not causing a strong reference cycle (a.k.a. retain
        // cycle).
    }
};
```

That way, you won't have retain cycle, but you don't have to worry about it getting exceptions or other problems that can result if you just used `weakSelf` alone.

This pattern is illustrated in "non-trivial cycles" discussion in the [Use Lifetime Qualifiers to Avoid Strong Reference Cycles](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011226-CH1-SW4) in the *Transitioning to ARC Release Notes* that David referenced.

Comment: Ah ok Rob, that's what I had in mind, and what it made sense: `weak references will not be retained`

Answer (score 0):

Weak references are captured weakly, so objects pointed to them are not necessarily kept alive for the lifetime of the block.

Comment: But the point here is related to the dance `__weak MyClass *self`. Where if you don't go with it, you will have a retain cycle.

Comment: Sure. Breaking cycles is what weak references are for. They don't behave any differently with respect to blocks.